# Issue with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs

My application seems to be fine. But when I click chrome's back or forward button, my URL is changed, but I see blank screen and empty `body` tag with `ng-view` attribute. I have put a `console.log` in each controller and I see that the controller of desired page is executed, but page is not rendered at all, just blank `body` tag.

How do I fix it? I am using angularjs with Ruby on Rails if it is important.

Comment: Do you see any error in your browser's console?

Comment: No errors are shown.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to migrate javascript libraries to `vendor` folder and move `ng-app` to `html` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using turbolinks. It's a bit tricky to make turbolinks and angularjs work together, I suggest you to take a look [here](http://kurtfunai.com/2014/08/angularjs-and-turbolinks.html)